# Librosa.display immediately disappears

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, signal-processing

I am following some example code from [Librosa documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.stft.html) in order to display a spectrogram of a STFT. The problem is that the spectrogram never appears, when I run the program in a terminal window, I briefly see a program launch (the same as would launch on a call to `plt.show()`) but it disappears immediately.

Do I need to explicitly call a method to show the `img` object in the code below? If not, what could be causing the plot to not show?

```
# read the .wav file
audio, sample_rate = librosa.load("/Users/user/Desktop/voice.wav")

# perform stft using librosa module
audio_stft_1000 = np.abs(librosa.stft(audio, n_fft=1000))
audio_stft_3000 = np.abs(librosa.stft(audio, n_fft=3000))

# create plots according to docs linked above 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

img = librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(audio_stft_1000,
                                                       ref=np.max),
                               y_axis='log', x_axis='time', ax=ax)

ax.set_title('Power spectrogram')
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax, format="%+2.0f dB")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple solution:

```
plt.show()
```